# UnexpectedTypeException in FormFactory.php

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'am under Silex ~2.0.
I have a problem with FormServiceProvider, I got this error :

> UnexpectedTypeException in FormFactory.php line 64: Expected argument of type "string", "SocialWall\Form\Type\CommentType" given

```
in FormFactory.php line 64
at FormFactory->createBuilder(object(CommentType), object(Comment), array()) in FormFactory.php line 39
at FormFactory->create(object(CommentType), object(Comment)) in routes.php line 23
at {closure}('2', object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array('2', object(Request))) in HttpKernel.php line 153
at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in HttpKernel.php line 68
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in Application.php line 496
at Application->handle(object(Request)) in Application.php line 477
at Application->run() in index.php line 11
```

my route.php

```html
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use SocialWall\Domain\Comment;
use SocialWall\Form\Type\CommentType;

// Home page
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    $articles = $app['dao.article']->findAll();
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig', array('articles' => $articles));
})->bind('home');

// Article details with comments
$app->match('/article/{id}', function ($id, Request $request) use ($app) {
    $article = $app['dao.article']->find($id);
    $commentFormView = null;
    if ($app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        // A user is fully authenticated : he can add comments
        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->setArticle($article);
        $user = $app['user'];
        $comment->setAuthor($user);
        $commentForm = $app['form.factory']->create(new CommentType(), $comment);
        $commentForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($commentForm->isSubmitted() && $commentForm->isValid()) {
            $app['dao.comment']->save($comment);
            $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Your comment was succesfully added.');
        }
        $commentFormView = $commentForm->createView();
    }
```

Form/Type/CommentType.php

```html
<?php

namespace SocialWall\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('content', 'textarea');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'comment';
    }
}
```

I have another error :
With PhpStorm I see handleRequest, isSubmitted, isValid and createView methods are not found.

Please save my day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixe it, on route.php line 23 :

```
$commentForm = $app['form.factory']->create(CommentType::class, $comment);
```

On CommentType.PHP :

```
<?php

namespace SocialWall\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;


class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('content', TextareaType::class);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'comment';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First parameter of the `createBuilder` method should be a string representing form type.

```
->createBuilder('form', object(Comment), array())
```

http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.html#method_createBuilder

Comment: Thanks a lot for help ! But How I do that with my code ? Because I use create fonction.

Comment: `create` has the same parameters http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.html#method_create

Comment: Yes, I see that, but how I can adapt this line : $commentForm = $app['form.factory']->create(new CommentType(), $comment); ?